# Extrude or move or give length in millimeters

Tags: units

So I have established that I need to work in metric and have set this in scene settings I have also set the units to millimeters.

[image]

I have then specified the appropriate scaling on the properties shelf (N).

[image]

However the major increments on the grid remain 1 meter and showing "User Ortho Meters x0.001" as the legend in the top left corner of the 3D Viewer.

[image]

But when I extrude for example :

Select Face E 2 This extrudes 2m

Select Face E 0.2 This extrudes 20cm

Select Face E 0.02 This extrudes 2mm

This is not what I was expecting. How would I go about setting this up so that I am working in mm. I.e. to extrude 2m I would:

Select Face E 2000

Thank you in advance of any ideas.

Comment: In your second image, Display menu, make the Scale: 1.000

Comment: That is odd, setting the scale for the scene should be enough. Did you scale your mesh in Object mode without applying the Scale (Ctrl+A)?

Comment: Hi 3fingeredfrog, yes I originally tried that, but doing that the grid disappears completely even when I zoom in

Comment: Hi cegaton, I did not scale my mesh at all. I was not aware that I needed to.